# iOS CLLocationManagerDelegate didUpdateToLocation is not being called

Tags: ios, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm creating an app that uses core location and this is my code:

the .h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>    
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<CLLocationManagerDelegate>    
@property(strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *manager;    
@end
```

the .m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize manager;
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.manager)
    {
        self.manager=[CLLocationManager new];
    }
    self.manager.delegate = self;
    self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation * currentLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", currentLocation);
    if (currentLocation != nil)
    {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    }
}
@end
```

the problem is `didUpdateToLocation` is not being called.
I tried putting a breakpoint inside of it and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS location tracking to work correctly, here are the prerequisites, and the order is of importance, too:

1. Define your class as `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.
2. Instantiate `CLLocationManager` instance.
3. Set its `delegate` to `self`.
4. Set its various properties (accuracy etc)
5. Call `[CLLocationManagerDelegate startUpdatingLocation]` when you intend to.
6. Listen to location updates within your delegate method `didUpdateLocations`, implemented within the class designated as `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

With your code, here are the things you need to correct:

```
-(IBAction)submit
{   
    [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (!self.manager)
    {
        self.manager=[CLLocationManager new];
    }
    self.manager.delegate = self;
    self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;     
}
```

In short, before telling it to start updating location, you need to instantiate it and set its properties right. Currently you are doing it the reverse way.

**UPDATE**

Also, your delegate method `didUpdateToLocation` is deprecated since iOS 6. You must replace it with [newer method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16), like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{    
    CLLocation * currentLocation = (CLLocation *)[locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Location: %@", currentLocation);
    if (currentLocation != nil) 
    {
        self.latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Nirav
tried it didn't work
sorry I'm just new to core location its the first time I use it
So maybe I'm making a really stupid mistake
I'll update my code If you'd be kind to check it again

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these keys to your Info.plist:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

And also request for the type you want to authorise if iOS8:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
        {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

So the system will display the alert "Allow "app" to access your location...? Allowing will start your location manager and `didUpdateLocations` will be called.